# R purrr capture input and outputs

Tags: r, logging, purrr

Maybe this is more like logging rather than just functional programming, but I was wondering if there was a more `purrr` like way to achieve a message of inputs and outputs/diagnostic messages.

This is useful to me as I'd like to use `sparklyr` in production and have a log of job statuses of queries over partitions.

```
library(magrittr)

# Helper to list input params with output
helper = function(x, y, z) {
  c(query = x, params = y, z) 
}

# For single parameters
log_results = function(param, functions, adjective) {

  # Cross the input vectors to apply each function to each parameter set
  crossed_args = purrr::transpose(purrr::cross2(param, functions))
  crossed_params = crossed_args[[1]] %>% unlist
  crossed_function_names = crossed_args[[2]] %>% unlist()

  # Parse to the query to wrap it with quietly
  parsed_functions = purrr::map(crossed_function_names, ~ adjective(eval(parse(text = .x))))

  # Tidy container for function calls
  df = dplyr::data_frame(function_name = crossed_function_names, f = parsed_functions, param = crossed_params)
  # Execute to get query results
  results_log = purrr::map2(df$f, df$param, ~ .x(.y))

  # Output results log as message
  purrr::pmap(.l = list(df$function_name, df$param, results_log), helper) %>% str

}
```

All this is doing is making a table of row-wise jobs to dispatch and returning the job with diagnostic messages. This is dumped to a log, so  if there was a failure, I can check which job failed.

```
log_results_quietly = purrr::partial(log_results, adjective = purrr::quietly)

> log_results_quietly(c(-1, 3, 4, 5), c("exp", "log"))
List of 8
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ query   : chr "exp"
  ..$ params  : num -1
  ..$ result  : num 0.368
  ..$ output  : chr ""
  ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
  ..$ messages: chr(0) 
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ query   : chr "exp"
  ..$ params  : num 3
  ..$ result  : num 20.1
  ..$ output  : chr ""
  ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
  ..$ messages: chr(0) 
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ query   : chr "exp"
  ..$ params  : num 4
  ..$ result  : num 54.6
  ..$ output  : chr ""
  ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
  ..$ messages: chr(0) 
...
```

I thought `invoke` might help, but I couldn't make it play nice with `quietly`.

Any suggestions on how this could better be done are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something, it could be rewritten as simply as:

```
cross(list(query = functions, params = param)) %>% 
  map(~ c(.x, adjective(eval(parse(text = .x$query)))(.x$param)))
```

I'm not sure why you `transpose()` the output of `cross()` and then `map2()` over it, it seems simpler to directly `map()` after `cross()`.

Also, do you really want your function to only have the side effect of printing something through `str()`, and return `NULL`?
I'd advise to rather return your list, then call `str()` on the result of the function.

Something like:

```
log_results_2 <- function(param, functions, adjective) {
  cross(list(query = functions, params = param)) %>% 
    map(~ c(.x, adjective(eval(parse(text = .x$query)))(.x$param)))
}
log_results_quietly_2 = purrr::partial(log_results_2, adjective = purrr::quietly)
res <- log_results_quietly_2(c(-1, 3, 4, 5), c("exp", "log"))
str(res)
```

(Notice it's ordered differently than yours because I called `cross()` with `functions` first. It can be easily tweaked)

```
# List of 8
#  $ :List of 6
#   ..$ query   : chr "exp"
#   ..$ params  : num -1
#   ..$ result  : num 0.368
#   ..$ output  : chr ""
#   ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
#   ..$ messages: chr(0) 
#  $ :List of 6
#   ..$ query   : chr "log"
#   ..$ params  : num -1
#   ..$ result  : num NaN
#   ..$ output  : chr ""
#   ..$ warnings: chr "production de NaN"
#   ..$ messages: chr(0) 
#  $ :List of 6
#   ..$ query   : chr "exp"
#   ..$ params  : num 3
#   ..$ result  : num 20.1
#   ..$ output  : chr ""
#   ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
#   ..$ messages: chr(0) 
# ...
```

Also I'm not sure what you meant with "play nice with `quietly()`". I was worried at first I would have problems with lazy evaluation, but I didn't.

If you want to play with `invoke()`, you can replace the `map2(df$f, df$param, ~ .x(.y))` line in your function with an `invoke_map()`:

```
all.equal(
  purrr::map2(df$f, df$param, ~ .x(.y)),
  invoke_map(df$f, df$param)
)
# [1] TRUE
```